# Detect multiple connected devices in Java

Tags: java, list, detect, removable-storage

I want to write Java codes that will meet the following requirements:

1. Detect multiple devices (removable storage) connected to the laptop
2. List down all devices connected to the laptop
3. Allow users to choose which device that should be used by the Java program

For example, when there are 2 USB devices, the Java program will detect them and then list them as (e.g. F:\, G:). Following this, the users can choose which device to use. Is there any way to do so?

I found this website http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/506/Detect-USB-removable-drive-in-Java useful to detect my thumbdrive that is connected, however, it is not able to detect more than one device.

Detect.java

```
public class Detect
{
    public String USBDetect()
    {
        String driveLetter = "";
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        File[] f = File.listRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
        {
            String drive = f[i].getPath();
            String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]);
            String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(f[i]);
            boolean isDrive = fsv.isDrive(f[i]);
            boolean isFloppy = fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]);
            boolean canRead = f[i].canRead();
            boolean canWrite = f[i].canWrite();

            if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive && (type.toLowerCase().contains("removable") || type.toLowerCase().contains("rimovibile")))
            {
                //log.info("Detected PEN Drive: " + drive + " - "+ displayName); 
                driveLetter = drive;
                break;
            }
        }

        /*if (driveLetter.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("Not found!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(driveLetter);
        }
        */

        //System.out.println(driveLetter);
        return driveLetter;
    }
}
```

List.java

```
public class List 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        File[] units = File.listRoots();

        for(File unit:units)
        {
            System.out.println(unit.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

This code helps me detect more than 1 removable drive but it also lists down the local drives. I believe I should include in some parts from the Detect.java for it to detect only removable drives. As for 2. and 3. I have not tried yet because I do not know how to start, since I have not found any relevant websites to reference to. I hope that you can provide me with any useful websites or codes that could meet the requirements above. Sorry I am new to Java.

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: I have included the codes that I currently have.

Comment: By using your code I not getting Local Drive `driveLetter`, I getting only removable disks `driveletters`

Comment: When I use the first code it detects only 1 removable drive but when I use the second code it detects all the drives including C:\ and D:\.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Detect
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Detect test = new Detect();
        test.USBDetect();
    }

    public void USBDetect()
    {
        String driveLetter = "";
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        File[] f = File.listRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
        {
            String drive = f[i].getPath();
            String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]);
            String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(f[i]);
            boolean isDrive = fsv.isDrive(f[i]);
            boolean isFloppy = fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]);
            boolean canRead = f[i].canRead();
            boolean canWrite = f[i].canWrite();

            if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive && (type.toLowerCase().contains("removable") || type.toLowerCase().contains("rimovibile")))
            {
                //log.info("Detected PEN Drive: " + drive + " - "+ displayName); 
                driveLetter = drive;              
                System.out.println(driveLetter);
            }
        }

        /*if (driveLetter.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("Not found!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(driveLetter);
        }*/

        //System.out.println(driveLetter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Posting the same code like in the question does not make it an answer!